# Is it possible that $2^{2A}+2^{2B}$ is a square number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

> Let A and B be two positive integers greater than $0$. Is it possible that $2^{2A}+2^{2B}$ is a square number?

I am having trouble with this exercise because I get the feeling the answer is no, but I cannot elaborate on the proof. So far what I thought was to assume that there is some integer $C>0$ such that  $2^{2A}+2^{2B}=C^2$. Then
$$(2^A+2^B)^2=C^2+2^{A+B+1}$$
I was trying to see if the previous expression could hold a contradiction but I got stuck. All I could find is that $C$ needs to be an even number but that doesn't seem to get me anywhere. I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you prove that $4^{A-B}+1$ is never a square?

Comment: Is there a certain reason you wrote "even powers of 2" instead of "powers of 4"? (At first I thought you meant "powers of 2 which are even numbers," or, in other words, "powers of 2 other than 1.")

Comment: You were close to something when considering $C$ being even, that is basically looking at the equation modulo $2$. Turns out, a really simple solution arise when you look at it modulo $3$ (see below).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let $A>B$. Then $2^{2A}+2^{2B}=2^{2B}(2^{2A-2B}+1)$ is a square implies $2^{2A-2B}+1$ is a square as $2^{2B}$ is a square. But this is impossible since $2^{2A-2B}$ is a square.

Answer (score 10):

Shubhrajit Bhattacharya's answer gives a simple, direct proof that $2^{2A}+2^{2B}$ cannot be a square. But just for fun, let's finish off the OP's approach (which I initially thought led to a dead end).

If $(2^A+2^B)^2=C^2+2^{A+B+1}$, then $(2^A+2^B+C)(2^A+2^B-C)=2^{A+B+1}$, which means that $2^A+2^B+C$ and $2^A+2^B-C$ are both powers of $2$, and obviously *different* powers of $2$, say $2^a$ and $2^b$ with $a\gt b$ and $a+b=A+B+1$. But this implies

$$2(2^A+2^B)=2^a+2^b$$

If we now assume, without loss of generality, that $A\ge B$, we have

$$2^{B+1}(2^{A-B}+1)=2^b(2^{a-b}+1)$$

Now $a\gt b$ implies $2^{a-b}+1$ is an odd number greater than $1$, from which it follows that we must have $A\gt B$ (otherwise the left hand side is a power of $2$, not a multiple of an odd number greater than $1$). This in turn implies $b=B+1$ and $a-b=A-B$, from which we get

$$a+b=(a-b)+2b=(A-B)+2(B+1)=A+B+2$$

in contradiction to $a+b=A+B+1$.

Remark: I was a little surprised by the nature of the contradiction here, and had to check my work carefully to make sure I hadn't made a stupid arithmetic mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Just do it.

Assume without loss of generality that $A \le B$ so

$2^{2A} + 2^{2B}=$

$2^{2A} (1 + 2^{2B-2A})=$

$(2^A)^2 [1 + 2^{2B-2A}]=$

$(2^A)^2 [(2^{B-A})^2 + 1]$.

So if that is a perfect square then we must have $(2^{B-A})^2 + 1$ being a perfect square.

But $(2^{B-A})^2$ is a perfect square so we have two consecutive perfect squares.  It should be easy to convince yourself that the only time that ever occurs is $0^2$ and $1^2$.  (Proof as addendum).

So the only way this can happen is if $(2^{B-A})^2 = 0$ and $(2^{B-A})^2 + 1=1$.

But $2^{B-A} = 0$ is not possible.

====

Addendume:  Then only two consecutive squares are $0$ and $1$.

Proof:  Suppose $m^2 = n^2 + 1$.  where $m,n$ are non-negative integers. $n^2 < m^2 = n^2 + 1 \le n^2 + 2n + 1= (n+1)^2$ so $n < m \le m+1$.  But the only integers between $n$ (exclusive) and $n+1$ (inclusive) is $n+1$ so $m = n+1$.  And so $n^2 + 1 = m^2 = (n+1) = n^2 + 2n + 1$ so $2n = 0$ and $n = 0$ and $m =1$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $2^{2A}+2^{2B}$ is a perfect square. Without loss of generality, assume $A \geqslant B$. Then, let $A-B=x$, where $x$ is a non-negative integer. It follows that we have:
$$2^{2A}+2^{2B}=(2^B)^2 \cdot (2^{2x}+1)$$
Now, if the LHS is a perfect square, then the RHS must also be a perfect square. It follows that $2^{2x}+1$ is a perfect square. Let this be $n^2$. We then have:
$$2^{2x}=n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$$
Now, we need $n-1$ and $n+1$ to both be perfect powers of $2$. This can only happen for $n=3$. However, even then, we would only have $2^{2x}=8$ which is impossible as $x$ is an integer. Thus, no solutions exist.

Comment: *"Now, we need n−1 and n+1 to both be perfect squares. This can only happen for n=3."* — Is 3-1 a perfect square?

Comment: @MarianD sorry, that was supposed to be perfect powers of 2. Not perfect squares. I have made the edit.

Comment: Oh no! Your original sentence *“It follows that $2^{2x}+1$ is a perfect powers of $2$.”* was correct (not grammatically, “power” instead of “powers” :-)). Your corrected sentence is not true, sorry.

Comment: @MarianD Lol, sorry about that, I was a bit hasty and made the edit in the wrong place. Should be fine now.

Comment: Yes, it is OK now.

Answer (score 1):

We would have $k^2=4^{A}+4^{B}\equiv 1+1= 2\pmod 3$, impossible as $k^2 \equiv 0,1 \pmod 3$.